# Coldfusion iPhone image upload

Tags: iphone, coldfusion

We have an existing web page which lets users upload images to the server. We would like to stretch it out so that iphone users can also upload images in this web form. Any ideas or third party tools?

I also found http://www.cliqcliq.com/support/quickpic/ but there no sample in coldfusion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

phonegap's your friend...

http://www.phonegap.com/

Use HTML CSS & JS to make an app

Camera photo (jpeg) can be posted to CF as a base64 encoded string

Answer (score 0):

Jquery also has a mobile library that came out that may be of use to you.

Comment: I will try jquery mobile. Thanks!

Comment: It appears jquery mobile can't help me in file upload through iphone coz safari restricts access to file system.